# flash attribute not working depending on the the redirect URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I tested the below using `Spring web MVC 4.3.5`.

The following controller shows an example of a flash attribute working properly after a redirect:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/redirection")
public class RedirectionController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RedirectionController.class);

    @RequestMapping(path="/pageA", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String foo(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
                      , HttpServletRequest request
                      ) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("foo", "bar");
        return String.format("redirect:%s", "/redirection/pageB.do");
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/pageB", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String boo(final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) {
        printModelAttributes(model);
        return "page-b";
    }

    private static void printModelAttributes(final Model model) {
        Map<String, Object> map = model.asMap();
        logger.info(String.format("model attributes are: %s", map.keySet()));
    }    
}
```

When we visit the `/pageA` path with our browser we are automatically redirected to `/pageB` and the controller method for `/pageB` sees the flash attribute as expected:

> 14:35:18,740 INFO [webgui.RedirectionController] (http-/127.0.0.1:8082-3) model attributes are: [foo]

However, if I change the return statement the produces the redirect String from:

```
return String.format("redirect:%s", "/redirection/pageB.do");
```

… to:

```
return String.format("redirect:%s", "/.."+request.getContextPath()+"/redirection/pageB.do");
```

… we are still redirected to the same `/pageB` path but this time the flash attribute is missing:

> 14:34:51,892 INFO [webgui.RedirectionController] (http-/127.0.0.1:8082-3) model attributes are: []

I am assuming that this is due to Spring MVC trying to be clever and trying to guess if the redirection will take us to another application (different context path) in which case it does not bother placing the flash attributes in the session as they won't be available anyways in the other application.

Apparently the presence of the `/..` in the redirect String causes Spring MVC to think that we are changing application.

My questions are:

- is this feature documented?
- is my explanation plausible or is this a bug?

Comment: How is this related to Adobe's `Flash`? Are you asking about `Flash-message`?

Comment: I created a sample spring boot 1.4.3 app, which uses spring 4.3.5, and using the code you provided I've been unable to recreate the issue. When using "redirect:/.." it does not redirect properly and on my localhost an IllegalArgumentException is thrown in RedirectView.sendRedirect